# SWIFTUI : navigate in view and go back

Tags: swiftui, swift5

I have a question about swift. How I can navigate into views ?

Now, I have my ContentView that display a launchScreen, or Login, or HomeView in a conditional (if).

```
    var body: some View {

    VStack {

        if (sessionStore.session != nil) {

            UserProfileView(userProfile: self.profile ??  UserProfile(uid: "", firstName: "", lastName: "", birth: "", email: "", phone: ""))

        } else if show || UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: initialLaunchKey){

            AuthentificationView().transition(.move(edge: .bottom))

        } else {

            PageViewContainer( viewControllers: Page.getAll.map({  UIHostingController(rootView: PageView(page: $0) ) }), presentSignupView: { withAnimation { self.show = true }; UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: self.initialLaunchKey) }).transition(.scale)
        }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(Color.backgroundColor)
    .onTapGesture { UIApplication.shared.endEditing() }
}
```

But if I am in the LoginView, even if my condition in contentView for HomeView become true, I'm not going to HomeView...

I navigate into view by a var in observable object (page =1 then page =2...) I think is not the better way...

```
struct AuthentificationView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var userSignup: UserSignup


    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            if (userSignup.page >= 1) {

                SignupView()
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), removal: .move(edge: .leading)))

            } else {

                LoginView()
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .leading), removal: .move(edge: .trailing)))

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I recommend adding some code that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I've edited my first post

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test your code (due to absent custom things), so just by experience try the following

- use explicit condition for every view with transition
- make transitions animatable
- make container holding transitions animatable

Like below (scratchy)

```
var body: some View {

    VStack {

        if userSignup.page >= 1 {

            SignupView()
                .transition(AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing), 
                removal: .move(edge: .leading)).animation(.default))

        } 
        if userSignup.page == 0 {

            LoginView()
                .transition(AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .leading), 
                removal: .move(edge: .trailing)).animation(.default))

        }
    }.animation(.default)
}
```

Comment: I have this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59502896/signup-with-email-firstname-lastname-using-swiftui-and-firestore and when I want to use the sessionStore.session to change the view display, nothing is happening...

Comment: I have found, I don't have the return info, it's only a local var... How I can have the var that indicates the user is logged ?